# How to insert into mongodb database a list of strings?

Tags: python, flask, pymongo

```
database = mongo_connect()
un = str(session['username'])

database.game.insert({'host': session['username'],
    'player_list':[un]})
```

If i do this, then when I retrieve player_list, I get a list of unicodes. How can I make it so that I get a list of strings? Thanks

Comment: Why would you want `str`s instead of `unicode`s?

Answer (score 1):

because [mongodb stores data in bson format, and since bson is utf8-encoded, you'll get only unicode strings](http://api.mongodb.org/python/2.4.2/tutorial.html#a-note-on-unicode-strings).

you can encode `unicode` into `str` anyway;

```
player_list = [x.encode('utf-8') for x in player_list]
```